# Python-Mysql No puedo usar metodos de mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

pude usar el conector de mysql con python y conectarme a la base de datos

```
import mysql.connector

conexion = mysql.connector.connect( user='root',
                                    password="meli2324!",
                                    host='localhost'#,
                                    #database='sys',
                                    #port='3306'
                                    ) 



print(conexion)                     

cursor = conexion.cursor()
```

bien el problema es que en la ultima linea, no me deja usar el metodo cursor. no accede, es como si no existiera ese metodo

tampoco funciona el metodo close()

```
conexion.close()
```

estuve probando y con un

```
from mysql.connector import (connection)
```

con eso pude acceder a los metodos, pero necesito porque Solo a mi me pasa este ERROR siendo que el primer bloque de codigo deberia funcionar

Comment: Tal vez la conexión es lo que está fallando y no el código. Prueba poner la conexión dentro de un `try..except` como se ve en el tercer bloque de código aquí https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html

Comment: pero si, estaria fallando no me tendria que devolver el famoso mensaje:

<mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x0000026B6BCB7D60>

no es asi?

Comment: Esperame un ratito. Voy a levantar un servidor mysql en mi máquina asi pruebo yo también.

Comment: gracias genio, creo que puede ser un tema de version
o algo asi porque si uso el 

from mysql.connector import (connection)

ahi si me toma, todo.

sera porque al instalar el modulo ese, luego cambie de ubicacion del archivo python donde esta el codigo ese?

nose si tendre problemas tambien al usar el otro import , jaja

Comment: No creo que la versión sea el problema. Sí posible que mover el archivo haya afectado la importación de los módulos pero no se la verdad, es un error bastante extraño.